# Change Document root of LAMP folder

Tags: apache, lamp, ubuntu-14.04

I need to change the document root to something else.

for example I want my root as  ~/Dropbox/www instead of /var/www/html

To achieve that I've changed my /etc/apache/sites-availabl/000-default.conf file
to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot ../../home/ahmar/Dropbox/www/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

when I restart the server it seems fine

But When I open my localhost

it gives me a forbidden error
with this message

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: check [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/650402/403-forbidden-errors-on-redhat-server) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Putting

"DocumentRoot /home/ahmar/Dropbox/www/"

It should fix the problem. :)